# Unity - How to move diagonally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have already defined forward moving and left moving. How do I make it diagonally (left and up moving)? Thanks forwards.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        player.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        ???
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        player.MovePosition(transform.position - transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: No need to define it, if you press W and A then both `if`'s will be applied and the object will move diagonally.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't.

Comment: Debug the code and verify if it enters on both IF's, it should be enough.

Comment: I already tested it, doesn't work. I have to make a two directional movement, because the system doesn't understand two kinds of MovePositions.

Comment: @Gusman MovePosition is only called once per FixedUpdate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's worth noting that your current code doesn't work due to a quirk of `Rigidbody.MovePosition()` - its documentation doesn't mention it, but for [the 2D variant of the method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html), it's mentioned that

> the actual position change will only occur during the next physics update therefore calling this method repeatedly without waiting for the next physics update will result in the last call being used.

So although both if statements would be entered when both keys are pressed, only the `MovePosition()` in the last one would take effect.

To address this, my suggestion would be to calculate a combined movement vector instead of calling `MovePosition()` right away. Then, apply the movement vector at the end, so you only ever need to call `MovePosition()` once:

```
Vector3 totalMovement = Vector3.zero;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    totalMovement += transform.forward;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    totalMovement -= transform.right;
}

// To ensure same speed on the diagonal, we ensure its magnitude here instead of earlier
player.MovePosition(transform.position + totalMovement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I also added for left and right movements a rotation movement so the player can turn around.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help out.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to hold onto your current structure, then this is what you need:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    player.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward - transform.right).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Vector addition is supported in Unity, so you can simply sum them together. You would also need to make sure that once this if statement is called, none of the others have a chance to check.

However, I'd suggest looking at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/566046/diagonal-movement.html for a cleaner solution. Gusman is right, there are ways to do this without explicitly defining each case.